# Address formatting for TIGER geocoder

Tags: python, postgis, geocoding, address, format

I'm making some test for the geocoder comparing it with google and I have noticed that the results depend a lot on the address format.

E.G.

These give addresses:

```
358 SEVENTH AVENUE MANHATTAN 10001
955 2ND AVENUE MANHATTAN 10022
530 AUDUBON AVENUE MANHATTAN 10040
```

Gives a wrong results, while these work just fine:

```
358 7th Ave, New York, NY 10001
955 2nd Ave, New York, NY 10022
530 Audubon Ave, New York, NY 10040
```

How reliable will be to go from the first group the second one using a library like [this](https://usaddress.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) one and some strings mapping when required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be reliable, I would imagine that the use of 'New York' versus 'Manhattan' as the issue that you are running into.

'New York' used here is consistent with the County/City name as it's a designation that is commonly interchange in New York City Boroughs. This database appears to be using 'New York' versus 'Manhattan' which is commonly used to describe the borough name.